# How to perform LINQ JOIN with WHERE

Tags: c#, linq, join

I need help to perform JOIN using LINQ with WHERE clause.
The problem is when CaseId in events is null(not all events are case related)
it results in NOT showing event.

Here is my code:

```
var queryEvents = (from e in db.events
                 join u in db.users on e.UserID equals u.UserID
                 join c in db.cases on e.CaseID equals c.CaseID
                 where e.UserID == Program.loggedUser.UserID || (e.UserGroupID == Program.loggedUser.UserGroupID && c.AccessLvl>0)
                 select new { User = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName, e.Name, e.Description, e.StartDate }).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate);

            gvAppointments.DataSource = queryEvents.ToList();
```

I found some examples on how to use LINQ LEFT JOIN using INTO but then I have problem with WHERE statement.I honestly don't know where to put it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What's the problem of turning the current `inner join` to `db.cases` into `left outer join` (using the well known LINQ query syntax pattern) and keep the `where` as is now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var queryEvents = (from e in db.events
             join u in db.users on e.UserID equals u.UserID
             join c in db.cases on e.CaseID equals c.CaseID into cases
             from subC in cases.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where e.UserID == Program.loggedUser.UserID || (e.UserGroupID == Program.loggedUser.UserGroupID && subC?.AccessLvl ?? 0 > 0)
             select new { User = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName, e.Name, e.Description, e.StartDate }).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate);

        gvAppointments.DataSource = queryEvents.ToList();
```

You only must be aware, that subC might be now null, so you have to go for a default value, accessing it's properties.

Comment: The way it is now it gives me syntax error: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int?'

Comment: But when I write like  subC.AccessLvl > 0 it works fine. But is it safe to leave it that way???

Comment: Uh, sorry, I think you need to wrap subC?.AccessLvl ?? in round brackets (). Most likely without this the app will crash with a null ref exception, if this query is not executed against a sql context but a solid list.

Comment: I tested subC.AccesLvl > 0 with all kind of scenarios and couldn't get an Exception.Thank you anyway you helped me a LOT.